# Arcobjects union method

Tags: java, arcobjects

I get an AutomatedException error when trying to run the union tool with the geoprocessor of arcobjects and don´t know how to solve this. This is my code:

```
GeoProcessor geoProcessor = null;
try {
    geoProcessor = new GeoProcessor();
    geoProcessor.setOverwriteOutput(true);
    String inputString = "...\\a.shp"+ ";" + "...\\b.shp";
    Union u = new Union(inputString, "...\\union.shp");
    geoProcessor.execute(u, null);
} catch (AutomationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Does someone have an example code for a working union or interception method? I found this post, but it doesn´t help me eather: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144625/intersect-tool-in-arcobjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found a solution:

```
String inputString = "'...:\a.shp' #; '...\b.shp' #";
```